# Facing issue with implementation of DATAPROVIDER

Tags: selenium, appium

I am facing the below issue when I am trying to implement `DATAPROVIDER` in excel sheet and want to execute the program in `appium` but facing issue.

FACING ERROR AS ----:

```
Data provider mismatch
Method: test([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=4, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=5, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=6, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=7, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=8, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=9, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=10, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=11, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=12, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=13, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=14, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=15, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=16, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=17, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=18, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=19, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=20, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=21, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=22, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=23, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(java.lang.String) LeadStatus]
    at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:982)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

please help me out on the same.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Below is my code ----:   @DataProvider(name = "ProcurementLead")
     public Object[][] Procurement() throws IOException
        {
            return new Object[][] {{"LeadStatus"},{"CustomerName"},{"MobileNO"},{"EmailID"},{"CustomerAddress"},{"pincode"},{"City"},
             {"ManufacturedYear"},
             {"ManufacturedMonth"},
             {"Colour"},
             {"KMs"},
             {"Owner"},
             {"LeadSource"},
             {"Make"},
             {"ModelAndVariant"},
             {"CustomerExpct"},
             {"BuyingQuote"}
          
             }

Comment: @Test(dataProvider="ProcurementLead")
        public void test(String LeadStatus, String CustomerName, String MobileNO, String EmailID, String CustomerAddress, String pincode, String City, String ManufacturedYear, String ManufacturedMonth, String Colour, String KMs, String Owner, String LeadSource, String Make, String ModelAndVariant, String CustomerExpct, String BuyingQuote, String RegdYear, String RegdMonth, String RegdNo, String Insurance, String RefSource, String ExecInfo, String StockVinNo) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

Comment: MobileElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email"));
      
      Thread.sleep(4000);
       
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
             
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(email));
             
       boolean isElementPresent = email.isDisplayed();
             
       System.out.println(isElementPresent);
       
       Thread.sleep(4000);

Comment: driver.findElementById("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email").clear();
             
       driver.findElementById("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email").sendKeys("newgen");
       
       log.info("Entered ID");
      
       driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/password")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/password")).sendKeys("super123");
       
       log.info("Entered password");
     
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email_sign_in_button")).click(); //to login

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add your code into your question. You could then delete the comments.

Comment: @Martin he is new to stack thought soo.. let me do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass all the arguments then use below code for data provider:

```
@DataProvider(name = "ProcurementLead") 
public Object[][] Procurement() throws IOException { 
return new Object[][] {
// first set of values
{"LeadStatus","CustomerName","MobileNO","EmailID","CustomerAddress","pincode","City", "ManufacturedYear", "ManufacturedMonth", "Colour", "KMs", "Owner", "LeadSource", "Make", "ModelAndVariant", "CustomerExpct", "BuyingQuote","RegdYear","RegdMonth","RegdNo", "Insurance", "RefSource", "ExecInfo", "StockVinNo"},

// second set of values
{"LeadStatus","CustomerName","MobileNO","EmailID","CustomerAddress","pincode","City", "ManufacturedYear", "ManufacturedMonth", "Colour", "KMs", "Owner", "LeadSource", "Make", "ModelAndVariant", "CustomerExpct", "BuyingQuote","RegdYear","RegdMonth","RegdNo", "Insurance", "RefSource", "ExecInfo", "StockVinNo"}

}
}
```

If you want to add more set of data you can add it.

Also observed that you have used explicit wait as well as Thread.sleep().
It is not recommended to use Thread.sleep().
Instead you can use, Implicit wait.

Next time before posting question, go through stackoverflow question posting guidelines. So that your question is easy to read.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked and i have applied same logic in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Data provider mismatch occurs when the data you are fetching from your external file is not matching with datatype that you have mentioned in the test.

In order to resolve this issue you can use below approach:

**Using Data Provider in below method:**
    @Test(dataProvider = "login", dataProviderClass = DataGenerators.class)
    public void tc_001_login_functionality(String uname, String pass, String expectedText) throws Exception

Now just comment every code within this method and just print the value that you that you are fetching like below:

```
System.out.println( uname + pass +  expectedText);
```

Now run the method, you will be able to find out which parameter is coming different from your external file.